# Create list from command line args in Scala

Tags: list, scala, command-line-arguments

In my scala main method, I use `import org.apache.commons.cli.{BasicParser, Options}` to parse command line arguments. One of the arguments is a Comma seperated string which lists which methods I want to run.

I have a map which maps the string to methods eg.

```
val methods = Map("first" -> first, "second" -> second, "third" -> third)
```

Now from my command line arg, I want to create a list of methods which I want to run. i.e. if I give arg as `"first,second"`, the list should contain `List(first,second)` but if I give arg as `"first,third"`, the list should contain `List(first,third)`

I know a list is immutable, so I can't iterate and add.

What is the scala way of doing this?

Comment: What is the type of first, second, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that CLI delivers a string with the comma separated words, consider separating the substrings of interest like this,

```
val methodNames = "first,second".split(",").toList
```

or separating the words like this,

```
val methodNames = "first,second".split("\\W+").toList
```

Hence to  fetch the methods from the list consider

```
methodsNames.map(methods)
```

Comment: But this creates a List of strings (which split itself does). I want a list of methods, where the methods are gotten from the <String, method> map.

Comment: @navinpai note update to question and addition to answer on fetching methods.